# Grayout background using onclick HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to have two onclick arguments inside a button tag like so:

```
    <div id="Spacer" align="center">
      <button id="button" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block'; " onclick="$('#grayout').toggle(900); return false;">
        <a id="Text">Click to go to Google</a>
      </button>
    </div>
```

And my CSS is this for the onclick argument:

```
 #grayout {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: black;
   opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

But this does not work. Is there any way to open the popup box called 'pop' and gray out the background? If this could be don't without any external java that would be a bonus too.

Comment: You can't have several `onclick` attributes. Just separate your statements with semicolons or call a function (or better, use `addEventListener`). Also mixing up jQuery and the standard DOM library seems questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block';
        $('#grayout').toggle(900);
    });
```

In a script or in a -tag

Explaination:
What happens here is you add an event listener for a click event on the element with the id of button. So when you click on #button javascript performs the code withing the curly brackets.